# I need to get the value of token id using Json path extractor instead of using Regex

Tags: jmeter

I need to get the value of token id using JSON path extractor instead of using Regex

Here is the response:

```
{  
   "username":"Test",
   "project_name":"Testing",
   "user_domain_id":"default",
   "roles":[  
      {  
         "name":"_member_"
      }
   ],
   "services_region":"regionOne",
   "user_domain_name":"Default",
   "enabled":true,
   "domain_name":null,
   "id":"9354ad0e4022423db85fa148c9876d30",
   "available_services_regions":[  
      "regionOne"
   ],
   "is_superuser":false,
   "token":"6265e8da4807429ea65febf0a2312091",
   "project_id":"5abf103686584fa09860f04d0887f181",
   "domain_id":null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[JSON Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) is the best way to get value from JSON, in your case token is in first level child of JSON, so use the following expression:

```
$.token
```

Another way is using expression:

```
['token']
```

for more expression syntax see [JSON Path](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/)

> . or []   child operator

Comment: tq so much @7294900

Comment: how to get  extracted token value in single variable by taking dammy sampler can u please suggest me

Comment: @Guruganesh put the response in Response Data field, and add JSON Extractor post processor to it